# How to plot only y-axis using seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

i am new to machine learning, and i want to compare the predicted and the actual value, now i want to compare this both of the data in plot to see if both the values are same or not.

**data:**

```
[-0.26112159,  1.84683522,  2.23912728,  1.58848056,  1.28589823,
        2.01355579, -0.144594  ,  0.8845673 , -0.19764173,  0.00837658,
        1.3515489 ,  0.18876488,  1.07088203,  1.11333346,  0.99854107,
        1.67141781,  1.74938417,  1.17907989,  1.57017018,  2.04269495,
       -0.10662102,  0.96283466, -0.01117658,  0.01610438,  1.31111783,
       -0.08608504, -0.09535655, -0.0227967 ,  1.82867539,  1.4492189 ]
```

this is my data sample for both A and B datasets

i want to plot like this,

[image]

I prefer using seaborn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seaborn provides some elaborated functions to display data. Internally it depends heavily on matplotlib. As the requested plot doesn't fall into the categories Seaborn excells at, it seems more adequate to employ matplotlib's scatter directly:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

A = [-0.26112159, 1.84683522, 2.23912728, 1.58848056, 1.28589823,
     2.01355579, -0.144594, 0.8845673, -0.19764173, 0.00837658,
     1.3515489, 0.18876488, 1.07088203, 1.11333346, 0.99854107,
     1.67141781, 1.74938417, 1.17907989, 1.57017018, 2.04269495,
     -0.10662102, 0.96283466, -0.01117658, 0.01610438, 1.31111783,
     -0.08608504, -0.09535655, -0.0227967, 1.82867539, 1.4492189]
B = A
x = np.arange(len(A))
plt.scatter(x - 0.2, A, marker='o', color='tomato', label='Dataset A')
plt.scatter(x + 0.2, B, marker='o', color='deepskyblue', label='Dataset B')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

To have crosses as markers, use `marker='x'` or `marker='+'`.

To draw a [swarmplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html) (very similar to a [stripplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html)) via Seaborn:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# A, B = ...
sns.swarmplot(x=np.repeat(['Dataset A', 'Dataset B'], len(A)), y=np.concatenate([A, B]))

plt.show()
```

[image: swarmplot]

A [kde plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) can be used to compare the statistical distribution. Here is an example with some noise added to make both sets a little different:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# A = ...
A = np.array(A)
B = A + np.random.normal(0,.1, len(A))
sns.kdeplot(A, label='Dataset A')
sns.kdeplot(B, label='Dataset B')

plt.show()
```

[image: kde plot]

Comment: could you please help me the same example with seaborn, i am new to python and i am using seaborn, thanks

Comment: forget about B, how can i just plot A with no x-axis

Comment: i am new to machine learning, and i want to compare the predicted and the actual value, so the predicted value are just an array, as shown in my question.

Comment: just now i figured out to use this

fig,_ax=plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,10))
sns.stripplot(y=predictions,ax=_ax[0])
sns.stripplot(y=y_test,ax=_ax[1],color='red')

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using seaborn, one way is the following. However, `stripplot` fits in very well for such case as you don't have to pass the x-values explicitly.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

sns.scatterplot(range(len(A)), A, marker='x', color='orange', label='Dataset A')
sns.scatterplot(range(len(A)), A+0.1, marker='x', color='blue', label='Dataset B')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just figured out a way to do so, please let me know if there is any better method to plot for comparing two arrays.

```
fig,_ax=plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,10))
sns.stripplot(y=predictions,ax=_ax[0])
sns.stripplot(y=y_test,ax=_ax[1],color='red')
```

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question and add this? And maybe clarify your exact question.